# Why does fetchAssoc() add extra blank row during csv import to mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, laravel-5, csv-import

I am using league csv and laravel 5 to extract data from csv file and import to mysql database. The import is successful but the script add an extra blank row to the database. So if the csv file has 5 rows then it will enter 6 into mysql, the 6th one being blank.

```
DB::table('repositories')->delete();
$csv = Reader::createFromPath($path_to_file);
DB::table('repositories')->insert($csv->fetchAssoc(['last_name','first_name', 'matricule', 'username']));
flash()->success('Repository updated successfully');
return redirect('repositories');
```

NB:

1. My CSV file does not contain an extra blank row
2. print_r($csv->fetchAssoc(['last_name', 'first_name', 'matricule', 'username'])) returns as 
   shown below:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [last_name] => test [first_name] => user
>   [matricule] => M39812 [username] => test ) [1] => Array ( [last_name]
>   => john [first_name] => doe [matricule] => M39849 [username] => john2015 ) [2] => Array ( [last_name] => [first_name] => [matricule]
>   => [username] => ) )

I can't figure out why array 2 is added to the result?

Comment: Are you sure that there is no extra line break at the end of the text file? This is a common mistake.

Comment: @Shadow there is none. I have doubled check that. I still can't figure out what is wrong and I don't want to ignore the problem or use a dirty solution such as popping off the empty array.

Comment: Are you sure, you checked the file using the same OS as your server. Sometime, the EOL format is different, and Windows might not recognise the new line.